# C++ duplicate symbol from function pointer

Tags: c++, duplicate-symbol

I have a 3 source files.  The main file has a function that use `if` statements to define a pointer:

```
main(int dispersalfn) {

if(dispersalfn == 0) {
    kernel1 = flatdisp;
  } else if(dispersalfn == 1) {
    kernel1 = expdisp;
  }

 [...more stuff...]

}
```

In `main.h` I have a definition for `kernel1`:

```
arma::vec (*kernel1)(arma::vec d, arma::vec m);
```

In `disp.cpp` I have definitions for `flapdisp` and `expdisp`:

```
arma::vec flatdisp(arma::vec d, arma::vec m) {
  return m;
}

arma::vec expdisp(arma::vec d, arma::vec m) {
  return (square(m) / (2*M_PI)) % exp(-m % d);
}
```

`disp.h` has corresponding definitions for `flatdisp` and `expdisp`:

```
arma::vec flatdisp(arma::vec d, arma::vec m);
arma::vec expdisp(arma::vec d, arma::vec m);
```

Finally `upfun.cpp` has a number of functions that call `kernel1`.  The functions in `upfun` 
are called by `main()`.

When I compile, I get an error:

```
 duplicate symbol _kernel in upfun.o and main.o for architecture x86_64
```

All my header files source each other have include guards, so I don't think that's it.  The idea is that when I call `main()`, I include variables to choose which function is used for `kernel1`. This worked until I broke up my functions into different files.  What causes this error?

Comment: Seems to be a linker problem do you use the #ifndef HEADER_H #define HEADER_H you should provide a working example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that you meant to say:

```
duplicate symbol _kernel1 in upfun.o and main.o for architecture x86_64
```

The linker is complaining that you have defined the symbol (a.k.a. variable) "kernel1" in more than one places.

The problem is that you have defined a variable "kernel1" in a header file main.h. This header file is getting included in more than one .cpp file. Therefore, you have effectively defined "kernel1" in more than one compilation unit.

The solution is simple. Move the definition of "kernel1" **to main.cpp** instead:

```
arma::vec (*kernel1)(arma::vec d, arma::vec m);
```

Update added to address comment:

It was pointed out the symbol "kernel1" is being used from another file as well.
In which case,

1. The definition of "kernel1" still needs to happen in main.cpp as
   described above.
2. Add an "extern" declaration of kernel1 in the main.h header file:

   ```
   extern arma::vec (*kernel1)(arma::vec d, arma::vec m);
   ```

This should address your problem.

Comment: When I do this, I get the error `upfun.cpp:18: error: ‘kernel1’ was not declared in this scope`.  Since the functions in `upfun` require `kernel1` (however it is defined in `main`), it needs to be in the header.  Per @Leonardo above, I have `#ifndef HEADER_H #define HEADER_H` include guards in all the header files.

Comment: @Noam Ross: I have updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: This partially addressed the issue.  It eliminated this error, but later, on loading, I got the error `Symbol not found: kernel1`.  It turns out I also had to have a default value for `kernel1` declaure in `main.cpp`.

Comment: "I got the error Symbol not found: kernel1". Noam, this will happen you did *NOT* add the definition of kernel1 in main.cpp. Can you please copy-and-paste the COMPLETE compiler/linker output?

Comment: Whoops, my mistake.   I didn't do #1 at first.  Your update is correct.